# El método paintevent no funciona si trabajo sobre un ScrollArea ¿qué puedo hacer para activarlo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

El código que estoy usando es:

```
import sys
from numpy import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import ui_pruebadibujoFandGBoxNoSB

class Balun(QWidget,ui_pruebadibujoFandGBoxNoSB.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        '''self.frame_2.paintEvent()'''      

        self.text = u'\u041b\u0435\u0432 \u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430\ \u0435\u0432\u0438\u0447 \u0422\u043e\u043b\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0439: \n\ \u0410\u043d\u043d\u0430 \u041a\u0430\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0430'

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        qp = QPainter(self.frame_2)
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawText(self, event, qp):

        qp.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 3))
        qp.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)        
        qp.drawLine(350, 250, 370, 270)#2, 2, 20, 32   


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Balun()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

El atributo self.frame_2  corresponde al frame donde quiero mostrar el dibujo. El dibujo sí se muestra, pero necesito agregarle a la ventana un `ScrollArea` y cuando lo hago se deja de mostrar el dibujo dentro del frame
¿a qué se debe y qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba añadiendo el super, no te sabria decir si funciona ya que no me corre tu aplicacion con el contenido que tengo xD pero es posible que no este pintando despues de lo que tu le indiques.

```
def paintEvent(self, event):

    qp = QPainter(self.frame_2)
    qp.begin(self)
    self.drawText(event, qp)
    qp.end()
    super(nombredetuclase, self).paintEvent(event)
```